# Append HTML Code from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i change this function which is currently appending a CSS class to a div on HTML

```
if (!this.sortDisabled) {
        var $th = $(this).addClass(table.config.cssHeader);
        if (table.config.onRenderHeader) table.config.onRenderHeader.apply($th);
}
```

to make to append this instead of adding class "table.config.cssHeader"

```
'&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>'
```

So my question explained is how can i get this

```
if (!this.sortDisabled) {
    var $th = $(this).addHTMLCODE(&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>);
    if (table.config.onRenderHeader) table.config.onRenderHeader.apply($th);
}
```

Comment: Incidentally: [`font` is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/font), so don't use that. Alternatives would include using a [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/span) with a specific class for styling, or perhaps an [`em`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/em), or [`strong`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/strong) element. Among many, many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using jQuery. You're pretty close; instead of `addHTMLCODE`, you need [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append), and you also need to quote the HTML:

```
var $th = $(this).append('&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>');
```